# How use React Routes with conditions and Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm struggling with creating an authentication with React Redux and Routes.

Depending on the variable responsible for authentication, the user gets a certain set of routes. But at the time of initial loading, when the variable has not yet received a value from the redux store, routes are displayed for a non-logged in user, i.e. registration page, and only then the necessary pages.

It turns out that every time you update the registration page flashes.

*Code in routes.js:*

```
export const RotesPage = ({ isAuthenticated }) => {
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <MainPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/schedule" exact>
            <SchedulePage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/tasks" exact>
            <TasksPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/money" exact>
            <MoneyPage />
          </Route>
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }

  if (!isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" exact>
          <LoginPage />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/register" exact>
          <RegisterPage />
        </Route>
        <Redirect to="/login" />
      </Switch>
    );
  }
};
```

*Code in App.js:*

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { loadUser } from "./actions/authAction"; 
import { AppNavbar } from "./layouts/components/AppNavbar";
import { RotesPage } from "./routes";

const App = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); 
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const isAuthenticated = auth.isAuthenticated;

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadUser());
  }, [dispatch]);

  return (
    <Router>
      {isAuthenticated && <AppNavbar />}
      <RotesPage isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

How can I fix it?

P.S. Sorry if I discribe it badly, 'cause I'm learning not only programming languages but English too.

P.P.S. It's my first Q here.

Thank you in advance =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your redux state set `isLoading` variable which initially will be `true`, once you get auth data set it to `false`.

Then in your App you can do something like:

```
  const auth = useSelector((state) => state.auth);
  const isAuthenticated = auth.isAuthenticated;
  const isLoading = auth.isLoading;

<Router>
  {isLoading ? (
    <div>Loading...</div>
  ): (
    <>
      {isAuthenticated && <AppNavbar />}
      <RotesPage isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />
    </>
  )}
</Router>
```